# Change String in loop

Tags: c#, string, foreach, user-controls

I have one `foreach` that will create `usercontrols` in my `form` for each `checkbox` selected.

And i have this: `pict.Tag["img0"].Text = img;` and this is in my usercontrol what i need is to change `img0` to `img1`, `img2`, `img3`... for each `usercontrol` created. can someone tell me or help me how can i change the value for each `usercontrol` created?

And please if you guys don't understand what i am asking just comment for i know and try to explain it better.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: What about `"img" + counter++`?

Comment: a `for` loop may work better as you'll have `i` to work with. Then you could do `"img" + i`.

Comment: Create an increasing integer (int i = 0 before the foreach loop, i++; right inside the loop) and use that (pict.Tag["img" + i].Text = img;)

Comment: Thanks @PatrickHofman that was simple and worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Will use `@PatrikHofman` answer because it's simple and works very well.

""What about `"img" + counter++`? – Patrick Hofman"""

Thanks you all!!

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
int i = 0;
String Name = "img";
foreach(var img in images)
{
    pict.Tag[Name + i.ToString()].Text = img;
    i++;
}
```